# Why cant I use PCA to find all stock factors?

Tags: factor-models, pca, eigenvalue

Why cant I run all the stocks in the stock market thru a PCA model, and use the resulting principal components to create a factor model to price stocks and then buy stocks under priced and short stocks overpriced according to said model? Does it have to with the fact that PCA is unsupervised?

Comment: What kind of supervision do you have in mind ? By which authority ? The question is strange. Nothing stops you from doing this. But don't loose all your money.

Comment: Kurt G.: https://www.ibm.com/cloud/blog/supervised-vs-unsupervised-learning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PCA is applying the mapping from the high dimensional space to the lower dimensional space linearly. Thus, any relevant factors which are not linear will not be discovered. Please consider reading the following: [Linear vs Non-linear dimension reduction](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/124534/how-to-understand-nonlinear-as-in-nonlinear-dimensionality-reduction/124545#124545).